# D3.js bar element not adding dynamically

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a basic example with dummy data to try and get my head around what is happening when adding or removing data to a graph in D3. The example fiddle can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/TomPlum/mae58joo/7/).

To my understanding, inside the **generateBars(data)** function;

I update the x and y domain, ensuring that the next call to the axes causes them to scale correctly:

```
testUpdateX.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.destination;}));
testUpdateY.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.p_in;})]);
```

Pass the new data variable from the parameter:

```
var bars = svg.selectAll(".testUpdateBar").data(data);
```

Update the current bars' x, y, width and height:

```
bars.transition().duration(2500)
    .attr("x", function(d) {return testUpdateX(d.destination);})
    .attr("y", function(d) {return testUpdateY(d.p_in);})
    .attr("width", testUpdateX.bandwidth() - 5)
    .attr("height", function(d) {return testUpdateHeight - testUpdateY(d.p_in);})
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        var maxIn = d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.p_in;});
        if (d.p_in < maxIn * 0.3) {
            return "red";
        } else if (d.p_in > maxIn * 0.3 && d.p_in < maxIn * 0.6) {
            return "orange";
        } else {
            return "green";
        }
    });
```

Then, append new "rect" elements to the new data via invocation of the `.enter()` function and applying the same attributes and styles to it:

```
 bars.enter().append("rect").attr("class", "testUpdateBar")
     .attr("x", //...)
     .attr("y", //...)
      etc...
```

Invoking `.exit()` and `.remove()` in order to remove the bars of any data that has been removed:

```
bars.exit().transition().duration(2500).remove();
```

Then finally, re-calling my axes in order to update them in accordance to the newly specified domain:

```
svg.select(".testUpdateXaxis").transition().duration(2500).call(testUpdateXaxis);
svg.select(".testUpdateYaxis").transition().duration(2500).call(testUpdateYaxis);
```

Why does the final bar for 'Spar' not appear? The y-axis correctly itself for it's new value and a space is created, yet no rectangle elements seems to be appended.

*Apologies for the unnecessarily long variable names. I was testing this within an existing file and wanted to ensure the names didn't conflict.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code. You have this inside your `generateBars` function:

```
var svg = d3.select("body");
```

Therefore, when you click the button you are in fact appending the `Spar` rectangle of your enter selection... **outside** the SVG!

It should be simply:

That is, nothing!

Here is the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pugya97h/

Comment: So by removing that line, `svg.someFunction()` is referring back to the initial instantiation of svg, which has the _actual_ SVG element stored in it? Updated fiddle with transition: https://jsfiddle.net/TomPlum/mae58joo/8/

Comment: Yes, that's correct: since you previously defined `var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")`, your `var svg` refers to the appended SVG. By the way, you can save a lot of code with a simple `merge()`: https://jsfiddle.net/fv8ypv4s/

Comment: I've looked at `merge()` in the D3 API [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#merge). I'm assuming it merges the new data with the old, even though you only pass it one parameter?

Comment: It doesn't merge data, it merge *selections*.